# Components inside partials

Tags: ractivejs

How can Ractive Components live inside partials?

I have a `FormInput` Component

```
<FormInput type="text" label="Please enter name" value="{{John Doe}}"/>
```

which translates to

```
<div>
  {{label}}: <input type="{{type}}" value="{{value}}">
</div>
```

There is also another component `Modal`

```
<div>
  {{>modalContents}}
</div>
```

When I create a `Modal` component with

`modalContents:'<FormInput type="text" label="Please enter name" value="{{John Doe}}"/>'`

the component isn't rendered at all, probably because ractive thinks it is just text. I know, I am missing something here... Is there a way to make it actually parse the component?

*Note: examples are simplified

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does work, but you need to make sure that the `FormInput` component is *registered*. One way is to register it globally...

```js
Ractive.components.FormInput = FormInput;
```

...but you can also register it when creating a new instance:

```js
var FormInput = Ractive.extend({
  template: '<div>{{label}}: <input type="{{type}}" value="{{value}}"></div>'
});

var Modal = Ractive.extend({
  template: '<div>{{>modalContents}}</div>'
});

var modal = new Modal({
  el: 'body',
  partials: {
    modalContents: '<FormInput type="text" label="Please enter name" value="John Doe"/>'
  },

  // register the component here
  components: { FormInput: FormInput }
});
```

There is a small syntax error in your example which may be relevant – it should be `John Doe`, not `{{John Doe}}`.

Demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/rich_harris/80w8o1bu/

Comment: Thank you very much, the problem was that I had not registered the Component!

As soon as I got it registered, everything worked as expected :)

TBW: Great work with ractive, @Rich Harris